# .NET User.config file is deleted on Citrix

Tags: .net, citrix, roaming

I have written a .NET app and use the built in User Settings to store user specific information. It works brilliant. The user.config file is stored in the Apps/Local directory.

Now, a client is running my app on Citrix. I recently figured out that their Citrix server is configured to clean out the Apps/Local directory when a session closes. As a result, all user settings are deleted between the sessions. Not good.

My question is how to get around this. Is there any way to configure the settings to store the user.config in the roaming profile instead of Apps/Local? (The roaming profil content (Apps/Roaming) is not cleared by Citrix) Has anyone run in to this situation besides me?

Regards
Karl

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with my application that uses a class inheriting from [System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) to get/set user settings by adding a [SettingsManageability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.configuration.settingsmanageabilityattribute.aspx) attribute to the settings properties, e.g.:

```
[UserScopedSetting, SettingsManageability(SettingsManageability.Roaming)]
```

With the Visual Studio settings designer, it looks like you can do the same via the properties window when a setting is selected in the designer, by setting the "Roaming" property's value to "True".